# syntax for outputting pairs of variables in R using rep function and for loop processing

Tags: r

I want to print out in r the following columns:
day date time1 timec1 time2 timec2 time3 timec3

I am taking this in stages. First get the rep and paste0 statements correct and then add day date and finally print.

```
paste0("time", 1:3) is ok
paste0("time timec" , 1:3) #variable pairs are in quotes, I need individual variables in quotes
rep(1:3,paste0("time" "timec"))
Error: unexpected string constant in "rep(1:3,paste0("time" "timec""
```

I also tried using for i in 1:3

```
m1=for (i in 1:3) {paste0("time", "timec")}
 m2=print(m1)
 Output:
 NULL
```

I am including my attempts. Any help you can give would be appreciated.
Thank you. MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with `paste0` and `rep`

```
paste0(rep(c("time", "timec"), 3), rep(1:3, each = 2))
#[1] "time1"  "timec1" "time2"  "timec2" "time3"  "timec3"
```

Another with `outer`

```
c(outer(c("time", "timec"), 1:3, paste0))
#[1] "time1"  "timec1" "time2"  "timec2" "time3"  "timec3"
```

You can add `"day"` and `"date"` to above output to get all the column names. For eg -

```
c("day", "date", c(outer(c("time", "timec"), 1:3, paste0)))
#[1] "day"    "date"   "time1"  "timec1" "time2"  "timec2" "time3"  "timec3"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I am also developing my skills in use of functions like the for i in 1:3 attempt. Any suggestions?  Your solution is really good.

Comment: @MaryA.Marion In R, very rarely you'll need a `for` loop. But for sake of learning if you want to use it, you can try `val <- c();
for (i in 1:3) {
  val <- c(val, paste0(c("time", "timec"), i))
}` where `val` is the final output.